# Program Allows User To Input 5 Student Names And Marks To Print A Report (loop)

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, input

I want the program to allow you to input 5 student names and student marks. However every time I run it, it doesnt accept the names of the students.

```
students=[]
for num in range(5):
    x=input("Enter name of students: ")
    students.append(x)

marks=[]
for num in range(5):
    y=input("Enter marks of students:")
    marks.append(y)

report = input("Do you want to print class report?: ")
if report == 'yes':
    print(x[0],":", y[0])
    print(x[1],":", y[1])
    print(x[2],":", y[2])
    print(x[3],":", y[3])
    print(x[4],":", y[4])
```

Comment: Please fix the loop indentation... Also, where is `Name`  defined?

Comment: even `i` is not defined. Plus give us your error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some working code:

```
n = 5

students=[]
for num in range(n):
    x=raw_input("Enter name of students: ")
    students.append(x)

marks=[]
for num in range(n):
    y=raw_input("Enter marks of students:")
    marks.append(y)

report = raw_input("Do you want to print class report?: ")
if report == 'yes':
    for i,j in zip(students, marks):
        print(i,':', j)
```

**Explanation**

Several issues resolved:

- Indentation is *crucial* in Python.
- Use `list.append` on variables that are actually defined.
- Use a loop with `zip` to cycle through pairs of [student, mark] data.
- Use `raw_input` instead of `input` in Python 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

```
while Name != "":
    i.append(x)
```

will loop (and append) forever if `Name != ""`... (and what is `i` and `Name`?)

and in python 2.7 you should use [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input):

a quick fix would be this:

```
for num in range(5):
    x=raw_input("Enter name of students: ")
    if x == "":
        break
    students.append(x)
```

although, why have a break condition and a loop up to 5 at the same time? why not just

```
for num in range(5):
    x=raw_input("Enter name of students: ")
    students.append(x)
```

Comment: But it won’t even let me enter the names of the students, it says “NameError: name ‘john’ is not defined”

Comment: @Help that is the effect of `input` in python 2: it tries to evaluate the string you enter...

Answer (score 1):

Not clear if that code would run as written anyway. `Name` and `i` are never defined.

In Python2, you need to use raw_input to accept input, otherwise, what you type will be evaluated internally by Python

Also, you can combine the loops to collect tuples rather than build parallel lists

```
students=[]
for num in range(5):
    x=raw_input("Enter name of students: ")
    y=raw_input("Enter marks of students:")
    students.append((x,y,))

report = raw_input("Do you want to print class report?: ")
if report == 'yes':
    for x, y in students:
        print(x,":", y)
```